# How to merge two rows with one different field value into one row with concatenated field

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables with ManyToMany relations, books, authors, author_books. Sometimes in my application book has more than one author, so as a response i would like to show all of the authors separated by comma,
Here is a code with join to get book title with authors and id=182

```
SELECT books.id,books.title,authors.full_name FROM books 
INNER JOIN author_books ON author_books.book_id = books.id 
INNER JOIN authors ON authors.id = author_books.author_id 
WHERE author_books.book_id=182
```

How from that:

[image]

get the result as

```
182|Beautiful Creatures|Kami Garcia, Margaret Stohl
```

Comment: Check whether your RDBMS supports something lilke `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL.

Comment: tag your  dbms           s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL there is a function called `GROUP_CONCAT()`, this function in MySQL is used to **concatenate data from multiple rows into one field.** 
This is an aggregate (GROUP BY) function which returns a String value if the group contains at least one non-NULL value. Otherwise, it returns NULL.
The syntax for this one is like this,

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN
GROUP_CONCAT ( [DISTINCT] col_name1 
[ORDER BY clause]  [SEPARATOR str_val] ) 
FROM table_name GROUP BY col_name2;
```

`col1, col2, ...colN`: These are the column names of the table.
`col_name1`: Column of the table whose values are concatenated into a single field for each group.
`table_name`: Name of the table.
`col_name2`: Column of the table according to which grouping is done.
Use of various clauses inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` function,

1. `Dinstinct`: It eliminates the repetition of values from results.
2. `Order By`: It sorts the values of the group in a
   specific order and then concatenates them.
3. `Separator`: By default, the values of the group are separated by the (, ) operator. In order to change this separator value, a Separator clause is used followed by a string literal. It is given as Separator ‘str_value’.

Input:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id    fname    lname   dept_id   strength  `
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1     Harry    Potter    2      Leadership
3      Hermione Granger  3      Hard-working
1      Harry    Potter   2      Responsible
```

Using simple GROUP_CONCAT() function:

```
SELECT emp_id, fname, lname, dept_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT ( strength ) as "strengths" 
FROM employee group by id;
```

Output:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id    fname    lname   dept_id   strength  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1     Harry    Potter    2      Leadership,Responsible
3     Hermione Granger   3      Hard-working
```

Comment: It's working as I excpected, thank you very much.